# responsive table img (splited images) html

Tags: html, css, image, split

I want to split images in my page and my html worked perfectly but I need to change it into responsive `html5`. I have already tried many methods,please someone help me.

I had tried to change CSS also, but it was not work for me, I'm not too good in this, so I need your help.

My html code:

https://jsfiddle.net/manuel_songokuh/bj4fmrje/

My link html images:

http://www.issr.it/QyksDrVpOq7h-MANUEL/OPUSCOLO/help/2.html

Comment: Please provide the code you currently have.

Comment: sorry i'm not understand your ask...code html is link above (first link)

Comment: Your code wasn't there when I commented initially. You can't make tabular data respond. There are 8 columns per row, and if you shrink down your page, they have nowhere to go, so they hold their space. If you need it to be responsive for mobile devices, I suggest converting your table to something like a UL/LI list.

Comment: maybe i'm bad explain you, i dont need responsive for mobile devices, i need flexible scala like as zoom respect to height of html view.. sorry i'm bad english and explain...sorry